# Beanstalkd in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, beanstalkd

I am in the process of integrating some sort of background service executor. I am thinking to use Beanstalkd for it. I Googled it everywhere but I could not find a decent bundle to do the job with nice documentation. Few I found were

- LeezyPheanstalkBundle
- drymek/pheanstalk-bundle

But these bundles do not describe everything from start to end like [this one](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4) from Laravel. Like listening for the job, sending arguments and so forth.

Is there any bundle for this or perhaps documentation? I found one nice one for Laravel with proper documentation and everything.

So, I am thinking if I chose to Laravel container for this job are there any tutorials regarding how to use Symfony bundles in Laravel. I found many for using Symfony bundles in Laravel but not  the vice versa.

Can someone please give me any insight in this matter.

Comment: Any reason why my question was down voted? Is it not a good question to ask in SO?

Comment: There are libraries such as https://github.com/bernardphp/bernard and bernardBundle that will provide much of the required infrastructure you need.

Answer (score 2):

Working with Beanstalkd is framework agnostic. You should be better and more easy for anyone if you would learn [Pheanstalkd](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk) library. You can install quickly with `Composer`.

Working with Beanstalkd is so simple that the two examples from the linked page covers most of the parts, the other more advanced stuff is also easy and at hand with a couple of function calls. You need to be clear with the [procotol](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt)

Comment: I am not trying to plug my own stuff but I created one bundle myself that will support Beanstalk, SQS, Redis and DB. https://github.com/nicholasnet/QueueBundle